# Increasing JRE Memory Usage in Eclipse

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I read in another question that you can increase the JRE memory allowance for an app through Window -> Preferences in Eclipse, but I can't seem to find anything related to heap memory allocation.  Editing -xms/xmx values in eclipse.ini doesn't help since those are for Eclipse itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe when Run > Debug Configuration (or Run Configuration), then Arguments tab and in the VM arguments input you can specify arguments you want to use there.

NOTE: Eclipse has this to say about `VM Arguments`

> VM Arguments: Values meant to change
>   the behavior of the Java virtual
>   machine (VM). For example, you may
>   need to tell the VM whether to use a
>   just-in-time (JIT) compiler, or you
>   may need to specify the maximum heap
>   size the VM should use. Refer to your
>   VM's documentation for more
>   information about the available VM
>   arguments.